# Ubuntu terminal scroll through suggestions

Tags: command-line

I'm trying to find a way to scroll through the suggestions made by the auto-complete feature in the gnome terminal.

For example if I type

```
sudo apt-get install xserver-
```

and use double tab, there are large amounts of suggetions going over a page.
 Is there a set of keys to scroll back and forth though these suggestions?

Comment: See Fabby's answer in that post. It's a bit verbose, but what you want is the `menu-complete` setting in it.

Comment: For better navigation through the suggestions I use `zsh`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The double tab will try to autocomplete or list the available files/commands/etc...

This double tab opened using more .

`man more`

```
 more is a filter for paging through text one screenfull at a time.
```

to move between screens you have to use the <kbd>Space</kbd> key and to move down one line, use <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

A nice answer provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7179642/how-can-i-make-bash-tab-completion-behave-like-vim-tab-completion)

> By default TAB is bound to the complete readline command. Your desired
>   behavior would be menu-complete instead. You can change your readlines
>   settings by editing ~/.inputrc. To rebind TAB, add this line:
>
> TAB: menu-complete

Now you can move between list of outputs using <kbd>Tab</kbd>